# Node.js - How to create a request which can access the url before the root path "/'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, url-shortener

I am trying to complete the freecodecamp project- url shortener in glitch.

glitch project link: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/url-sh0rtn3r

What i am able to do currently is:-

- inside a **POST** request take the url to be shortened, convert it to a shorturl, add both to a database, and
- inside a **GET** request search for the shorturl(appended to the url rootpath) and redirect to the original url...

the shortened url for `https://www.freecodecamp.com`
becomes `https://url-sh0rtn3r.glitch.me/api/shorturl/9575` where 9575 points to the original url i.e. https://www.freecodecamp.com

Now i was wondering if i can somehow shorten the url further to be something like `https://initialpart/api/shorturl/9575`

But im stuck trying to figure out how to access the initialpart as a parameter inside a request where the path is pointing to whatever comes after initialpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the "initialpart" (domain) from your request object with `req.headers.host`. In your case this would return "url-sh0rtn3r.glitch.me" as a string. You can then use that in your app however you like. You can also get the rest of the request URL path with `req.url`, which in the above example would return "/api/shorturl/9575" as a string.